# Start Azure Machine Learning algorithms from python or r script

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, parallel-processing, automation

Is there any possibility to execute Azure machine learning models from inside a Python or R script?

My requirement is to run a large but changing number of ML algorithms on multiple given data sets. I could either hard wire all sets to all algorithms, but this is very complex and not flexible.

So the idea was to wire the data sets into the Azure-embeded Python script, write the program logic in Python, and start the ML algorithms form within (e.g. a for Loop) in the Python script.

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think to execute Azure ML models from inside a Python or R script is possible in principles. You can try to follow the offical tutorials for [Python](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-execute-python-scripts/) or [R](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-r-quickstart/) to know how to use the `Execute Python script` or `Execute R script` module for implementing your wants in the Azure ML studio.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, we work intensly with custom Scripting in Azure. For Automation, we now developed a small C# application that triggers Azure web services. Some development effort, but very useful :-)